# How to test spa js modules with resharper testr jasmin?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, resharper

After reading about javascript unit testing / bdd in VS I found that you could use a combination of:

```
- ReSharper - support for PhantomJS headless + Jasmine/QUnit
- Testr - mock Require dependencies
```

I used Jasmine in a test script and was able to successfully run some simple tests, with functions declared in the same file.

However, I could not find / build a working end to end example for testing a js module with dependencies. I am trying to build on the example used in the SPA Jumpstart example by John Papa.

So given a people.js viewmodel module that has a dependency in datacontext.js:

```
define(['services/datacontext'],
 function (datacontext) {
var peopleViewModel = {        
                       title: 'People page'
                      };
return peopleViewModel;
})
```

Folder Structure:

```
/App/Viewmodels : people.js
/App/Services : datacontext.js
/App/Tests : peopletests.js
```

What do I need to add in a peopletests.js to make this test run?

```
describe("My Tests Set", function () {
 it("People Title Test", function () {
   expect(peopleViewModel.title()).toEqual("People page");
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm currently dealing with the same issue. It would be nice to be able to configure resharper's jasmine test runner to work with requirejs.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. add require.js as a reference path
2. add a require.config script as a reference path
3. load require modules.

peopletests.js:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/require.js"/>
/// <reference path="~/App/requireConfig.js"/>

describe("My Tests Set", function () {
var people;

beforeEach(function () {
    if (!people) { //if people is undefined it will try to load it
       require(["people"], function (peopleViewModel) {
            people = peopleViewModel;
        });
        //waits for people to be defined (loaded)
        waitsFor(function () { 
            return people;
        }, "loading external module", 1000);
    }
});

 it("People Title Test", function () {
   expect(people.title).toEqual("People page");
 });
});
```

requireConfig.js:

```
//beware of the port, if your app is runing in port 8080 
//you need to specified that to require since resharper whould use a random port 
//when running tests 
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/App/',
    paths: {
        people: 'ViewModels/people',
        dataContext: 'Services/datacontext'
    }
});
```

people.js

```
define(['dataContext'],
 function (datacontext) {
var peopleViewModel = {        
                       title: 'People page'
                      };
return peopleViewModel;
})
```