# State of Jasmine Unit Test support of Resharper 2017: Debug mode and AMD modules supported?

Tags: unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine, resharper, amd

I currently use Chutzpah to run and debug Jasmine Unit tests that include AMD/require.js modules. I would like switch to the test runner of Resharper 2017. However, Resharper does not seem to fully support Jasmine Unit Tests?

A. Example jasmine test:

```
/// <reference path="../../bower_components/requirejs/require.js" />
/// <reference path="../../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" />

describe('dummy example test', function() {
  it("should return bar", function () {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

The Test can be run with Resharper but the Debugging option is disabled:
[image]

B. Example test with module definition:

```
/// <reference path="../../bower_components/requirejs/require.js" />
/// <reference path="../../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" />

define(['Squire'], function(squire) {

  describe('dummy example test', function() {
    it("should return bar", function() {
      expect(true).toEqual(true);
      alert('has been executed');
    });
  });

});
```

If I start that with Resharper the test never ends and the it method is not called.

Is it true that Resharper 2016 does not yet support the Debugging of Jasmine unit tests and neither the usage of AMD modules with unit tests? Or do I need to somehow adapt my Resharper settings to get Debugging and AMD/requirejs modules to work?

Here are my current settings:
[image]

(Since both Chutzpah and Resharper 10 use outdated versions of Jasmine I am also open for further suggestions that integrate well with VisualStudio.)

Edit: Resharper 2016 seems to support Jasmine Versions > 2.0.

Related (not up to date?) articles:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427836
- https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5528577
- http://www.neovolve.com/2015/01/30/resharper-jasmine-and-requirejs/
- [Jasmine and Requirejs in Resharper 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216032/jasmine-and-requirejs-in-resharper-7)
- [How to test spa js modules with resharper testr jasmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234707/how-to-test-spa-js-modules-with-resharper-testr-jasmin)
- [Front end javascript testing using Require and Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743437/front-end-javascript-testing-using-require-and-resharper)
- [How do you debug Jasmine tests with Resharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222098/how-do-you-debug-jasmine-tests-with-resharper?rq=1)
- [Jasmine tests in Resharper don't stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131548/jasmine-tests-in-resharper-dont-stop-executing?rq=1)

**Edit**

The questions have been originally posted for Resharper 10. They are still valid for Resharper 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ReSharper 2016.1:

A. Debugging JavaScript tests is not supported. Here is the [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-286219).

B. AMD is not supported. Here is [the related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427836).

Comment: Same situation for Resharper 2017.1

Comment: Karma support for Resharper might be a solution for this, since Karma supports requirejs and debugging. However, Karma support is not yet implemented for Resharper: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-386732