# Resharper jasmine loop tests always aborted

Tags: jasmine, resharper

i'm searching for a while to find a resharper test integration of looped jasmine tests.

See the little example (working excelent when run directly with karma test runner) BUT Resharper always aborted this test without any hint whats wrong:

```
describe('this is my looping test!', function() {
var input = [1,2,3];
var output = [10, 20, 30];

function test_my_times_ten(input, output) {
it('should multiply ' + input + ' by 10 to give ' + output, function() {
expect(input * 10).toEqual(output)
});
}

for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
test_my_times_ten(input[x], output[x]);
}
});
```

Is there any possibility to run loop tests?
Thanks, Jana

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757264/state-of-jasmine-unit-test-support-of-resharper-2016-debug-mode-and-amd-modules